# Type mismatch in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Basically my Macro will extract data from certain columns from a particular file and then paste over the other file's worksheet. But now I get the error message of

> Type mismatch in Excel VBA

at this line:`With Worksheets(wkbSourceBook)`

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim row1 As Integer
Dim hello As Range
Dim hello1 As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook

        With Worksheets(wkbSourceBook)
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For i = 4 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            row = rngSourceRange.row
            Set hello = Range("O" & row & ",Q" & row & ",W" & row)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            row1 = rngSourceRange.row
            Set hello1 = Range("AD" & row & ",AI" & row & ",AF" & row)
            hello.Copy hello1
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
            '~~> Change Sheet2 to relevant sheet name
        End If
        End With


    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Workbook object as an argument to a function that takes either integer (index) or string (worksheet name).

Worksheets("Sheet1")
or 
Worksheets(1)

Comment: But for my case is there any ways to use workbook object as argument?

Comment: You want to use the name of the workbook object. `With Worksheets(wkbSourceBook.Name)` but that prob won't work because the sheet name won't include the file extension (.xlsx or .csv or whatever).  So store the name in a string variable and then remove the extesnion.

Comment: Set wkbSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    With wkbSourceBook.Worksheets(1)

Comment: What if I want to select the second worksheet? Is it a good choice to use Application.InputBox to let the user to select?

Comment: I guess you need to get that information from the user somehow and that is one way to do it. IF it was safe to assume that the workbook was previously saved with the correct worksheet open, you could use wkbSourceBook.Activate and read from Activesheet or set Activesheet.Index as default value for your InputBox.

Answer (score 0):

`wkbSourceBook` is already declared as `workbook`

To work with the `worksheets` in a `workbook` use this code:

```
With wkbSourceBook.worksheets("name of worksheet")
```

or

```
With wkbSourceBook.worksheets("index of worksheet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think maybe you could use:

```
Set wrkSheet = ActiveSheet
With wrkSheet
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```